# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database still unable to fix issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-database

This question has already been asked by the people but going through the steps from many of them I am still unable to fix the problem at my end, please help.
i also added the permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

here is the logcat error.

```
07-17 15:23:58.253 14526-14526/com.techmobile2.yogahome E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.techmobile2.yogahome, PID: 14526
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.techmobile2.yogahome/com.techmobile2.yogahome.SettingPage}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:235)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:219)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:468)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:190)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:182)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:874)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:752)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:727)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
    at com.techmobile2.yogahome.Database.YogaDB.getSettingMode**(YogaDB.java:21)**
    at com.techmobile2.yogahome.SettingPage.onCreate**(SettingPage.java:41)**
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
```

here is the the yogaDB.java file i will mention the line number also

```
public class YogaDB extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "yoga.db";
private static final int DB_VER=1;

public YogaDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
}

public int getSettingMode()
{
    **SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();** //THIS is line 21
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = {"Mode"};
    String sqlTable = "Setting";

    qb.setTables(sqlTable);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,null,null,null,null,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Mode"));
}

public void saveSettingMode(int value)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE Setting SET Mode = "+value;
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

and here is the SettingPage.java and i will also mention line number

```
public class SettingPage extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnSave;
RadioButton rdiEasy,rdiMedium,rdiHard;
RadioGroup rdiGroup;
YogaDB yogaDB;
ToggleButton switchAlarm;
TimePicker timePicker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting_page);

    //Init view
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    rdiGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rdiGroup);
    rdiEasy = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdiEasy);
    rdiMedium = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdiMedium);
    rdiHard = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rdiHard);

    switchAlarm = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.switchAlarm);

    timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    yogaDB = new YogaDB(this);

    int mode = yogaDB.getSettingMode(); this is line 41
    setRadioButton(mode);

    //Event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveWorkoutMode();
        }
    });

}

private void saveWorkoutMode() {
    int selectedID = rdiGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if(selectedID == rdiEasy.getId())
        yogaDB.saveSettingMode(0);
    else if(selectedID == rdiMedium.getId())
        yogaDB.saveSettingMode(1);
    else if(selectedID == rdiHard.getId())
        yogaDB.saveSettingMode(2);
}

private void setRadioButton(int mode) {
    if(mode == 0)
        rdiGroup.check(R.id.rdiEasy);
    else if(mode == 1)
        rdiGroup.check(R.id.rdiMedium);
    else if(mode == 2)
        rdiGroup.check(R.id.rdiHard);
}
```

and my sql database file name is yoga.db
please help me to solve my problem

Comment: where is `public void onCreate(`?

Comment: Why not try `Room`? It takes care of all the trivial stuff and lets you focus on the important ones. Here the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) and a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ajaysaini.official/building-database-with-room-persistence-library-ecf7d0b8f3e9)

Comment: The Android SQLite Asset Helper library [is deprecated according to its GitHub page](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). Would it be better to use the built-in [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) or [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) instead?

Comment: Instead of extending using SQLiteAssetHelper use SQLiteOpenHelper it will implement two methods onCreate and onUpgrade.

Comment: It usually occur when you are accessing sqlite database from multiple thread and not all of them can access Database at once

Comment: please suggest me the solution

Comment: i am beginner so can anybody fix my code and provide my fix code here because i can,t get how to do above steps  i make a setting in which i have 3 options to select easy medium and hard for that i use database so please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Issue:** Most of the times **SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException** occurs when you are access your sqlite database from multiple threads. Let say you have opened the database in one thread and trying to access the database in another will cause **SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException** exception.

**Solution:** Make a singleton object of your SQLiteOpenHelper class and always use the same instance for multiple threads.

**Sample:**

**DBHelper class:**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  public synchronized static DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (dbHelper == null) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    return dbHelper;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    //...
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    //...
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
private static SQLiteDatabase database;


DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
if (database == null) {
  database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

**Note:** Never close the SqliteDatabase instance yourself android system does it for you.

Comment: great thank u for your help i fix the issue i use short form of database name and database verson as db_name and db_ver these short form causing error when i use full form then all set up